# Creating a new entity in Symfony2 with Doctrine by using the "namespace"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

You know that in Symfony2 a new entity can be defined as in the following example:

```
use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product;

public function defaultController() {
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('Pippo');
    $product->setPrice(19.99);
    ....
    // Use Doctrine EntityManager to store the Product object
}
```

Suppose that you know that the *Product* class has the following namespace: "**AcmeHomeBundle:Product**". It would by nice to create the *$product* object by using the namespace (e.g. by using the EntityManager or something similar).

```
public function defaultController() {
    $item = createObjectFromNamespace("AcmeHomeBundle:Product");
    $item->setName('Pippo');
    $item->setPrice(19.99);
    ....
    // Use Doctrine EntityManager to store the Item object
}
```

Do you know if this is possible?

Suppose that you have a string that provides the entity type

Comment: I guess that a partial answer can be found [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#reference-proxies), in the official Doctrine docs. However, the getReference from EntityManager only returns a reference to an existing entity. What about a new one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do this...

```
$entityInfo = $this->em->getClassMetadata("entityNameSpace:entityName");
$entityMember = $entityInfo->newInstance();
```

If you wanna use a setter method by string:

```
$entitySetMethod = "set".\ucfirst("entityDataMemberName");
\call_user_func(array($entityMember, $entitySetMethod), $parameter);
```

Comment: Wow! It works! I just added the __toString function to my classes (the returned string is, for instance `'\Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article'` for the `Article` entity). Of course, I suppose that the code to run a method also works, but I use the method names directly!

Comment: Check out [The PropertyAccess Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html) for nice setters and getters.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to, you can do this:

```
$product = new Acme\JournalBundle\Entity\Product();
$article = new Acme\JournalBundle\Entity\Article();
```

But you'd have to type it out every time you wanted to create a new entity in that namespace.  If you simply used a use statement at the top of you class:

```
use Acme\JournalBundle\Entity\Product,
    Acme\JournalBundle\Entity\Article;
```

You could then create new articles and products with a simple:

```
$product = new Product();
$article = new Article();
```

They do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer to the question. You are not using a generic namespace, e.g. passed through a variable to the controller, because you know which object you are going to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

*Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product* **IS** the namespace of your entity. *AcmeStoreBundle:Product* is just an alias for the namespace to be used in DQL as a shorter alternative to the real namespace.

Why would you want to create objects with aliased namespace? I suppose you could create some kind of a factory using alias to map it to a real namespace, create an object and return it. But what's the point?

Entity aliases are defined via Configuration: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Configuration.html#153

you can not only set them but also retrieve, so if you really need this functionality you should be able to do this with Configuration instance.

It's hard to find anything about entity aliases in Doctrine docs. Symfony docs [explain the purpose of it a little](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration):

> alias - Doctrine offers a way to alias entity namespaces to simpler, shorter names to be used in DQL queries or for Repository access. When using a bundle the alias defaults to the bundle name.

Comment: Maybe I did not explained the point in the appropriate way! I just want to get an instance of a **new** entity by using the entity namespace. Suppose I have two entities with namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product and Acme\JournalBundle\Entity\Article, I'm looking for a method capable to get an instance of a new Product and a new Article, e.g. `$product = getNewEntity(Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product);` and `$product = getNewEntity(Acme\JournalBundle\Entity\Article);`. Or I must write `$entity = new Product();` and  `$entity = new Article();`.